# Ruby Axlsx gem grouping summary rows top icon(+/- icon should be top)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, axlsx

Currently I am Using axlsxgem in one of my project for grouping functionality, I am able to use the grouping functionality, but one place where I’m struggling is to outline summary rows and -/+ icon should be on top instead of bottom

Comment: Please post a related code on it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, it's a little bit late, but anyway

There is PR on github that's adding this functionality
https://github.com/randym/axlsx/commit/c80c8b9d9be5542471d66afcc2ce4ddd80cac1f7

But, latest release (2.1.0.pre) on rubygem doesn't contain it
So you need to download it directly from github
Now you can set -/+ icon on top instead of bottom with next code:

```
workbook.add_worksheet(name: worksheet_name) do |sheet|
  sheet.sheet_pr.outline_pr.summary_below = false
  sheet.add_row('row1')
  sheet.add_row('row2')
  sheet.add_row('row3')
  sheet.outline_level_rows 1,2
end
```

[Picture with result there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s61w5.png)